Are out-of-ecliptic oblique interplanetary transfer orbits more efficient than in-ecliptic transfers?
Most illustrations and animations of interplanetary transfer orbits show simplified, coplanar circular planetary orbits and classical Hohmann transfers in the ecliptic plane.
Reality is a bit messier. Planetary orbits have an inclination WRT the ecliptic (except, by definition, the Earth’s orbit).
LEO launches from the Earth usually produce an orbit with an inclination equal or greater than the launch site’s latitude (28.6* for Cape Canaveral,  45.6* for Baikonur). Of course, this inclination is in relation to the Earth’s equator which has an obliquity of 23.5* WRT the ecliptic. Putting all this together means an efficient launch to LEO will produce an inclined orbit WRT the ecliptic.
If this inclination is corrected to align with the ecliptic using thrust, it will cost delta-V.
Changing the orbital inclination is expensive in terms of delta-V, and is more expensive the closer the spacecraft is to the body it is orbiting. So why bother “correcting” the inclination? Why not design the transfer orbit at the same inclination (to the ecliptic) as the most efficient LEO launch?
Every inclined elliptical solar orbit crosses the ecliptic twice. The flight plan could be chosen so the spacecraft departs Earth at one node (perihelion) and arrives at the destination at the other node (aphelion). No inclination "correction" burn needed.

On arrival, the lowest energy insertion would result in an inclined (or polar) orbit around the target planet. But inclined orbits are usually preferred to equatorial orbits for planetary survey spacecraft.

When a spacecraft is leaving Earth's sphere of influence, its velocity relative to the Sun is dominated by Earth's velocity relative to the Sun (which is about 30 km/s), and not by the spacecraft's velocity relative to Earth (a few km/s). So you would want that these two velocities align closely if you want the spacecraft to reach, for example, Mars's orbit. Changing the inclination of a 30 km/s orbit is very expensive.
Besides, even if a spacecraft starts in a LEO orbit at a high angle to the ecliptic plane, you don't need to change its inclination as long as Earth's velocity relative to the Sun lies within the orbit's plane (which you can achieve by launching the spacecraft at the right time of day). Then, if the spacecraft accelerates at the right point of its orbit, it can leave Earth's SoI with its velocity relative to Earth being parallel to Earth's velocity relative to the Sun, because this velocity still lies within the spacecraft's orbital plane (relative to Earth). The spacecraft won't lie exactly in the ecliptic plane; it will be slightly above or slightly below. But the distance to the ecliptic plane will be much smaller than its distance to the Sun, so the inclination of the resulting orbit around the Sun will be pretty low.

isn't ~30km/s already in the pocket whatever the injection's inclination, and what's to lose regarding inclination is suboptimal benefit from remaining rotational ~1.6km/s?

@user721108 30 km/s are already in the pocket, but if you want to have a higher speed, to raise the apoapsis to the radius of Mars's orbit, the most efficient way to do it is to point your additional velocity (the spacecraft's velocity relative to Earth) in the same direction as these 30 km/s. I don't understand the second half of your question.
